# How can I use an array that was altered in another method?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array declared at the class level (`gameGrid`), which I then altered in one method, but now I need to take that altered method (now filled with `"."`) and do more to it in another method (`printGrid`). My professor helped me with all the code that contains JRD in the comments, so I need to keep those ideas. I have a `return` statement, but that isn't helping the situation. This program is meant to be a VERY simple PacMan game. I'm using Java 8, but can only use the most basic of concepts: variables, basic data types, arrays, control statements, string methods, only one class, and having multiple methods are ok.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PacManGame
{

static char [][] gameGrid;      // Define here so all methods can use it.  JRD.
static int X, Y;                //Variables for number of grid rows X, and columns Y  

public static void main(String[] args)
{
int numMoves; // How to keep track of # of moves user makes before winning game

Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

System.out.println();
System.out.print( "Enter the number of rows you would like in your game grid: " );
X = input.nextInt();
System.out.println();
System.out.print( "Enter the number of columns you would like in your game grid: " );
Y = input.nextInt(); 
System.out.println(); 

buildGrid(X, Y);  // Calls buildGrid method 
playGame();  // Need to start the game which includes printing the menu.  JRD.

} // Closes main method

public static void buildGrid(int X, int Y) // Return the built grid so other methods can use it. JRD. // Method for actually building the grid
{
    gameGrid = new char[X][Y]; // Array built from user's input for dimensions, with char. Defined at class level.   JRD.  
    int totalGridSize = X * Y;               // Gets the total grid size
    int cookieTotal = totalGridSize / 5;     // Calculates the 20% of cookies that will be on grid

    int theCookies = (int)(cookieTotal*Math.random())+1; //Assigns the randomly generated number  

    int i, j, k = 0;                         // Initialize loop counters
    for (i = 0; i < X; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < Y; j++)
                {
                    gameGrid[i][j] = '.';

                }
        }
    return gameGrid[i][j];
 } // Closes buildGrid method

public static void printGrid()
{
    char currentGrid [][] = new gameGrid[i][j];
    currentGrid[0][0] = '<';


}
}
```

**EDIT:** Here is my new code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PacManGame
{

    static char [][] gameGrid;      // Define here so all methods can use it.  JRD.
    static int X, Y;                //Variables for number of grid rows X, and columns Y  
    static int theCookies;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    int numMoves; // How to keep track of # of moves user makes before winning game

    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print( "Enter the number of rows you would like in your game grid: " );
    X = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print( "Enter the number of columns you would like in your game grid: " );
    Y = input.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println(); 

    buildGrid(X, Y);  // Calls buildGrid method 
    playGame();  // Need to start the game which includes printing the menu.  JRD.

    } // Closes main method

    public static char[][] buildGrid(int X, int Y) // Return the built grid so other methods can use it. JRD. // Method for actually building the grid
    {
        gameGrid = new char[X][Y]; // Array built from user's input for dimensions, with char. Defined at class level.   JRD.  
        int totalGridSize = X * Y;               // Gets the total grid size
        int cookieTotal = totalGridSize / 5;     // Calculates the 20% of cookies that will be on grid

        theCookies = (int)(cookieTotal*Math.random())+1; //Assigns the randomly generated number  

        int i, j = 0;                         // Initialize loop counters
        for (i = 0; i < X; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < Y; j++)
                    {
                        gameGrid[i][j] = '.';

                    }
            }
        return gameGrid;
     } // Closes buildGrid method

    public static char[][] printGrid(char[][] gameGrid )
    {
        gameGrid[0][0] = '<';
        int i, j = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < X; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < Y; j++)
                    {
                        gameGrid[theCookies][theCookies] = 'O';  
                    }
            }
        return gameGrid;
    }

    public static void printMenu() 
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println( "Choose from the following menu:");
        System.out.println( "1) Turn left");
        System.out.println( "2) Turn right");
        System.out.println( "3) Move");
        System.out.println( "4) Exit");
    } 

    // public static int playGame(int choice)
    public static void playGame() // Don't need to return anything. Add passed grid.  JRD.
    {
        int numMoves = 0; // Move declaration here.  JRD. // Will be used to keep track of # of moves
        int choice; // This is only used locally and not externally.  JRD.


        do
        {
            printGrid(gameGrid); // Print grid JRD.
            printMenu(); // Print menu for each command.  JRD.
            Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
            System.out.print( "Enter your menu choice (1-4): ");
            choice = input.nextInt();

            switch (choice)
            {
            case 1:

                System.out.print(">");
                break;    
            case 2:

                System.out.print("^");
                break;
            case 3:

                System.out.print("V");
                numMoves++;

                break;
            }
        System.out.println( "If you would like to see the menu again, enter 1: " );
        int menuChoice = input.nextInt();
        if (menuChoice == 1)
            {
                printMenu();
                break;
            }
        }
        while (choice != 4);

        System.out.print( "Thanks for playing! You took " + numMoves + " moves to eat all the cookies." );


    } // Closes playGame method

} // Closes PacManGame class
```

Comment: The comment on `buildGrid` says "Return the built grid", so why not return the whole grid instead of something like a element of the grid? (actually it is out-of-range and it cannot return anything because its return type is `void`)

Comment: I've changed it to char instead of void, but it still won't compile... all three parts of the right side of "new gameGrid[i][j]" give errors.

Comment: I'm not wanting to just return an element, I want the whole X*Y grid filled with "." to then layer theCookies and the PacMan "<" onto.

Answer (score 0):

Have the grid creation method return the grid

```
public static char[][] buildGrid(int X, int Y) // Return the built grid so other methods can use it. JRD. // Method for actually building the grid
{
    char[][] gameGrid = new char[X][Y]; // Array built from user's input for dimensions, with char. Defined at class level.   JRD.  

    // the same as original code, omitted

    return gameGrid;
} // Closes buildGrid method
```

and have the grid modification method be passed the grid and modify it

```
public static void printGrid(char[][] currentGrid)
{
    currentGrid[0][0] = '<';
}
```

How to use the methods:

```
char[][] grid = buildGrid(X, Y);
putStartOnGrid(grid);
```

---

Another choice: you made `gameGrid` a member property, so you may not want to return it and have functions just use the member property.

```
public static void buildGrid(int X, int Y) // Return the built grid so other methods can use it. JRD. // Method for actually building the grid
{
    gameGrid = new char[X][Y]; // Array built from user's input for dimensions, with char. Defined at class level.   JRD.  

    // the same as original code, omitted

    // remove the return statement
} // Closes buildGrid method

public static void printGrid()
{
    // you already have built gameGrid, so you don't have to try to create it again here
    gameGrid[0][0] = '<';
}
```

Comment: Ok, I made your suggested changes, which fixed the previously described errors, but now another method (that I didn't paste above) is being affected. putStartOnGrid has to be passed to playGame, so I changed it to the same char[][] return type as you indicated for buildGrid. I've added a return statement for currentGrid, but it says cannot find symbol. The line of code is putStartOnGrid(currentGrid); Should it be different?

Comment: It should be different if it doesn't compile.

Comment: lol, perhaps the better phrased question would be, "How should I change it?"

Comment: Define what you need, pass what callee need as the argument or use what is defined. Please post a [Minimal, Completel, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to have us do further examination.

Comment: Note: please don't break the question. *Append* new code to the question if you want to post it instead of *overwritting* the existing code.

Comment: Whoops, I saw your comment after I pasted over previous code.

Comment: `currentGrid` is not defined neither as class property nor local variable in `playGame`. Use `gameGrid` instead.

Comment: `printGrid` is better for the name of method to print the grid than `putStartOnGrid`.

Comment: Yay!! It compiles, thanks a million, so... this leads to my next hurdle. How can I pull the randomly generated theCookies to putStartOnGrid too and how do I apply something that is an integer as a character 'O' onto the array??

Comment: thanks for the tough love, lol. I've edited my code again, basically I duplicated what I did in buildGrid.